# SQL to join the table with DISTINCT values

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

I'm trying to LEFT JOIN two tables via ODBC connection in Excel, but then is joined it returns multiple values as table tblMapSizes does not contain unique values. Trying to add DISTINCT but it's throwing an error "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

```
LEFT JOIN tblMapSizes size ON c.SIZE_1 = (select DISTINCT(SUPPLIER_SIZES) from tblMapSizes)
```

tblMapSizes contains columns: ID, SUPPLIER_SIZES, SIZES.

If anyone knows a solution please help...

Cheers!

FULL CODE HERE:

```
SELECT

c.GROUP_NO,
c.GROUP_NAME,
c.DEPT_NAME,
c.CLASS_NAME,
ISNULL(c.BRAND, c.CLASS_NAME) as BRAND,
c.MAIN_SEASON,
c.SUB_SEASON,
c.SUB_NAME,
ISNULL(c.PRODUCT_TYPE, c.SUB_NAME) as PRODUCT_TYPE,
ISNULL(c.PL_CYCLE, 'New/Continuity') as PL_CYCLE,
c.ITEM,
CAST(c.ITEM as int) as ITEM_VALUE,
c.ITEM_DESC,
c.ITEM_PARENT,
CAST(c.ITEM_PARENT as int) as ITEM_PARENT_VALUE,
c.VPN,
c.SUPP_COLOUR,
c.ARNOTTS_COLOUR,
c.SIZE_1,
size.SIZES as SIZE_WEB,
c.SIZE_2,
c.RETAIL_PRICE,
c.EAN,
CAST(c.EAN as bigint) as EAN_VALUE,
c.WH_SOH,
c.STOCK_ON_HAND,


ISNULL(ISNULL(odi.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,l.WebProductStyleID),CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Oxfo', c.SIZE_1) = 1 THEN CAST(c.ITEM_PARENT AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'OX' ELSE c.ITEM_PARENT END) as "WEB_ID",
case when row_number() over (partition by ISNULL(ISNULL(odi.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,l.WebProductStyleID),c.ITEM_PARENT) order by (select 1)) > 1 then 0 else 1 end as OPTION_COUNT,
CASE WHEN SUM(c.STOCK_ON_HAND) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ITEM_PARENT) > 0 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as IN_STOCK,
SUM(c.STOCK_ON_HAND) OVER (PARTITION BY c.ITEM_PARENT) as STYLE_SOH,
CASE WHEN c.PL_CYCLE = 'Discontinued' OR CHARINDEX('Dum', c.CLASS_NAME) > 0 OR b.WEB_ALLOWED = 'No' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as CONGRUENCY,
ISNULL(b.CUTOUTS,'DN') as USE_COUTOUTS,
CASE WHEN c.ITEM_PARENT = CASE WHEN w.ITEM = c.ITEM THEN c.ITEM_PARENT ELSE NULL END THEN c.ITEM_PARENT ELSE NULL END as MARKED_FOR_WEB_WEB_ID,
CASE WHEN w.CREATE_DATETIME IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS MARKED_FOR_WEB_SKU,
w.CREATE_DATETIME,
CASE WHEN odi.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS PUBLISHED,

cast(odi.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE as datetime) as PD,

CASE WHEN odi.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PUBLISHED_COUNT,
CASE WHEN odi.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE IS NULL AND co.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE IS NOT NULL AND amp.IMAGE_DATE_UPLOADED IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS READY_TO_UPLOAD,

CASE WHEN amp.IMAGE_DATE_UPLOADED IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS IMG_UPLOADED,
amp.IMAGE_DATE_UPLOADED as IUD,
co.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE,
CASE WHEN co.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS COPY_COMP,
CASE WHEN tr."CREATE DATE" IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as TRANSFERRED_TO_PACKSHOT,
tr."CREATE DATE" as TTPD,
CASE WHEN io.DATE IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as IMAGE_ORDER,
io.DATE as IOD,

wcid.ONLINE_FLAG as DW_ONLINE_FLAG_WCID,
wcid.PUBLISHED as DW_PUBLISHED_FLAG_WCID,

REPLACE(ISNULL(ISNULL(odi.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,l.WebProductStyleID),CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Oxfo', c.SIZE_1) = 1 THEN CAST(c.ITEM_PARENT AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'OX' ELSE c.ITEM_PARENT END),'_','') as REPLACED


FROM tblCrystal  c

LEFT JOIN tblODIPublishedCSV odi ON c.ITEM = odi.SKU
LEFT JOIN tblWebIDLegacy l ON c.ITEM = l.SkuId
LEFT JOIN tblMapSizes size ON c.SIZE_1 = (select DISTINCT(SUPPLIER_SIZES) from tblMapSizes)
LEFT JOIN tblBrands b on CAST(c.GROUP_NO AS VARCHAR(10)) + '_' + c.BRAND=b.PRIMARY_KEY
LEFT JOIN tblMarkedForWeb w on c.ITEM=w.ITEM
LEFT JOIN tblDWCopy co on ISNULL(ISNULL(odi.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,l.WebProductStyleID),CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Oxfo', c.SIZE_1) = 1 THEN CAST(c.ITEM_PARENT AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'OX' ELSE c.ITEM_PARENT END) = co.WEB_ID
LEFT JOIN tblAmplianceReport amp on ISNULL(ISNULL(odi.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,l.WebProductStyleID),CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Oxfo', c.SIZE_1) = 1 THEN CAST(c.ITEM_PARENT AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'OX' ELSE c.ITEM_PARENT END) = amp.WEB_ID
LEFT JOIN tblTransfers tr on c.ITEM=tr.SKU
LEFT JOIN tblImageOrder io on c.ITEM_PARENT=io.ITEM_PARENT

LEFT JOIN MV_REP_PUBLISHED_WCID_LEVEL wcid on REPLACE(ISNULL(ISNULL(odi.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,l.WebProductStyleID),CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Oxfo', c.SIZE_1) = 1 THEN CAST(c.ITEM_PARENT AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'OX' ELSE c.ITEM_PARENT END),'_','') = wcid.PRODUCT_ID

WHERE c.ITEM_PARENT IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY WEB_ID DESC
```

Comment: The query you posted looks broken, and would not run in any SQL flavor which I have ever seen.  Is this your actual query?

Comment: Sorry, the actual query has 78 lines, but the line that is working looks like this:
LEFT JOIN tblMapSizes size ON c.SIZE_1 = size.SUPPLIER_SIZES
However, it returns multiple lines and I only want it to return one line

Comment: You need to show us some data here.  Without that, I'm afraid no one will be able to help.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just added the full code to my comment

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, could you try using `WHERE IN` instead of strict equality, i.e. use this:

```
LEFT JOIN tblMapSizes size
    ON c.SIZE_1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT(SUPPLIER_SIZES) FROM tblMapSizes)
```

This should make that specific error go away.  As to whether it be logically correct is another story.  You would need to explain the logic behind the join further.

Comment: the query was running but ran out of space, so I guess need something with less resources intense...